# Send {%A_ThisHotKey%} don't work always

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to use Send {%A_ThisHotKey%} into one my AHK script. Problem is it doesn't always works. Example:

```
!Tab::Send {%A_ThisHotKey%}
```

How can I make this work in all cases?

Answer (score 0):

In some cases that code would send AutoHotkey into an infinite loop if it didn't ignore the Send statement (as I'm guessing it does in this particular case).  If you want it to not ignore the send statement you can use InputLevel and SendLevel.

There is also a difference between the hotkey definitions and what gets sent via Send, so a hotkey definition of `!Tab` would actually get sent as `!{Tab}`, not `{!Tab}` as your code would be interpreted.